# create shape file (.shp) for polygon in C#

Tags: c#, gis, esri

I want to create shape file which can be used with GIS solution maps.
The situation is like this. User will draw some polygon on the maps by clicking on it. So i have the long-lat to draw the polygon.

Now i want to export this long-lat to shape file so it can be also shown on to the other GIS application.

I dont know anything about shape files, so will the creation of shape file is tough job?
Can anyone point me where should i start the searching ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: one more c# library: http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it from the doc

http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf

Well, of course, don't do that.

Google for shapefile library c# will certainly help you.

One good lib to start with is SharpMap : http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/

Other options here (not that young)
http://www.justkez.com/creating-a-shapefile-from-c-net-what-are-the-options/

Comment: Thanks, i am going to try SharpMap